# Why different build sizes while building apk on windows machine and mac ? Ionic 4 Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am building a application using `Ionic 4` with `Angular`. While taking prod/debug build on windows (win 10, 64 bit) machine, I'm getting `APK` size `23MB`. Whereas when I build `APK` on Mac machine, its `10.30 MB` only. There isn't any difference in local contents of project.

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing the same build type? The build is much larger when compiled in debug mode.

Comment: @rtpHarry Yes prod release build

Comment: did you find answer to yyour question?

Comment: In my case it was problem with source code. On windows machine source code was going to build